# Java Multithreading Communication does not work

Tags: java, multithreading, communication

Guys,
I'm learning something about Java Multithreading. My code as follows:

Class :ATM

```
package com.frank.threadlearning;

public class ATM {
private String atmNo;
private boolean isAvailable = true;

public ATM(){
    this("ATM-00");
}

public ATM(String s){
    this.atmNo = s;
}

public String getATMNo(){
    return this.atmNo;
}

public synchronized void useATM(){
    try{
        if(!isAvailable){
            System.out.println(this.atmNo + " is unavailable. Please wait...");
            this.wait();
        }
        isAvailable = false;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is using " + this.atmNo);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(this.atmNo + " is available.");
        isAvailable = true;
        this.notifyAll();

    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getStatus(){
    return this.atmNo + " is available? " + this.isAvailable;
}


}
```

Class: ATMUser

```
package com.frank.threadlearning;

public class ATMUser implements Runnable{
private ATM atm;
private String name;

public ATMUser(ATM atm, String s){
    this.atm = atm;
    this.name = s;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public void run(){
    System.out.println(this.name + " tries to use the " + this.atm.getATMNo());
    this.atm.useATM();
}

}
```

Class : ATMRoom

```
package com.frank.threadlearning;

public class ATMRoom {

public static void main(String[] args){
    //Define two ATM objects.
    ATM atm1 = new ATM("ATM-01");
    ATM atm2 = new ATM("ATM-02");
    //Define six ATMUser objects.
    ATMUser user11 = new ATMUser(atm1,"Frank");
    ATMUser user12 = new ATMUser(atm1,"Kate");
    ATMUser user13 = new ATMUser(atm1,"Mary");
    ATMUser user21 = new ATMUser(atm2,"John");
    ATMUser user22 = new ATMUser(atm2,"Soy");
    ATMUser user23 = new ATMUser(atm2,"Claire");

    Thread thread11 = new Thread(user11,user11.getName()+"Thread");
    Thread thread12 = new Thread(user12,user12.getName()+"Thread");
    Thread thread13 = new Thread(user13,user13.getName()+"Thread");
    Thread thread21 = new Thread(user21,user21.getName()+"Thread");
    Thread thread22 = new Thread(user22,user22.getName()+"Thread");
    Thread thread23 = new Thread(user23,user23.getName()+"Thread");

    thread11.start();
    thread12.start();
    thread13.start();
    thread21.start();
    thread22.start();
    thread23.start();




}


 }
```

I expected the result like this:

> Kate tries to use the ATM-01
>
> KateThread is using ATM-01
>
> Frank tries to use the ATM-01
>
> ATM-01 is unavailable. Please wait...
>
> Mary tries to use the ATM-01
>
> ATM-01 is unavailable. Please wait...
>
> Soy tries to use the ATM-02
>
> SoyThread is using ATM-02
>
> John tries to use the ATM-02
>
> ATM-02 is unavailable. Please wait...
>
> Claire tries to use the ATM-02
>
> ATM-02 is unavailable. Please wait...
>
> ATM-01 is available.
>
> MaryThread is using ATM-01
>
> ATM-02 is available.
>
> ClaireThread is using ATM-02
>
> ATM-01 is available.
>
> FrankThread is using ATM-01
>
> ATM-02 is available.
>
> JohnThread is using ATM-02
>
> ATM-01 is available.
>
> ATM-02 is available.

However, in fact, the following output has never appeared.

> XXX is unavailable. Please wait...

So is there anyone who can tell me and explain it to me?
Thank you.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Because useATM method is synchronised, so only one thread at a time can enter a given ATM's useATM method.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to sleep outside the monitor. In terms of the code: Use a synchronized block (`synchronized(this){...}` for the first bit of useATM. Then comes the try and the sleep inside the try. Finally a second synchronized block for the last part of useATM.  This will get the effect you are looking for.

One last thing, though: Instead of `if( ! isAvailable )` use `while( ! isAvailable )`. The reason is that there is no guarantee that the waiting thread will find `isAvailable` true upon returning from `wait`.